# Does the Bot Framework Emulator uses Direct-Line-API to communicate over the Bot Connector?

Tags: architecture, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm new to the Microsoft Bot Framework and I wanted to ask if my understanding of the general architecture is correct.

I stumbled across the following architecture [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfqeA.png)
Imagine I built a simple Echo-Bot with the given template from Microsoft and now I'm testing my Bot locally with the Bot Framework Emulator.

My current understanding is that when I'm interacting with the Bot Framework Emulator the Emulator uses the Direct-Line-API to communicate with the Bot Connector which communicates to my local Bot Web API. Or can I see the Bot Framework Emulator as a channel like Skype, Facebook, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: [Emulator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator) uses [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), which uses [Directline-JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS). So, when you're using the Emulator, you're using the WebChat channel.

However, Emulator, just added the [Bot Inspector](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/content/CHANNELS.md) to recent releases. This allows you to attach to conversations on other channels like Skype or Facebook and view the conversation, live, through the emulator. See the link above for setup instructions, but the gist of it is:

1. Add the inspector middleware to your bot
2. Use ngrok or an [Azure Service Bus Relay](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/04/16/debugging-your-locally-hosted-v4-bot-using-azure-relays/) to connect Bot Inspector to your Hosted Bot
3. Start a chat with your bot in a channel, and type the code Bot Inspector gives you (`/INSPECT attach <UUID>`)
4. Your conversation is then attached to Emulator and you can view all traffic between your bot and the user (you) in that channel

Note: Bot Inspector is super new. There's still some kinks to work out and instructions are a little sparse, but it works well, otherwise. You can view samples that already have the Inspector Middleware code here:

- [JS/Node](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/testbot)
- [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TestBot)

Note: Bot Inspector Mode is different from the [Inspector Pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#view-detailed-message-activity-with-the-inspector)